# Audio Mixing Circuit

Tags: amplifier, audio, lm386

So I'm working on a audio mixing circuit, and based on some research I settled on the following circuit:

[image]

My question is whether or not the circuit will work as intended. I feel that the process of mixing the signals in such a way seems overly simplistic and I might be missing something obvious. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: It's all down to what you "intended". That involves being able to mind read or you coming clean with a specification.

Comment: What do you exactly expect from this circuit? What are the input signals/output signal?

Comment: Mixing audio is a rather simplistic thing, however given that you don't show any values for the passives involved I have my doubts that you know what they are for and why you would want to filter there and by how much. You might be able to get more insights by simulating your circuit.

Comment: Mixing audio is an artform that has simple tools but many ways to use them. There are literally hundreds or thousands of way to approach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is overly simplistic and may not always work as intended.

Specifically, if either of the inputs is (a) fed from an appreciable source impedance and (b) drives a second output, that second output will hear crosstalk from the other inputs. It should be obvious why, and you can easily calculate the level of crosstalk when you know all the impedances.

So it's not something you'd want in a recording studio.

(If neither of those conditions holds, then this circuit will actually work, provided the input resistors are high enough to prevent the inputs from damage by being connected together)

The classic mixing configuration is a "virtual earth" mixer, based around an inverting amplifier configuration (e.g. using an opamp, NOT a power amp like an LM386). This holds the mixing node (the opamp's inverting input) at ground potential so there is no crosstalk between inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, exactly the kind of information i was looking for, and for not being completely obtuse about it.

Comment: Yea normally you have a mixer 'driver' into potentially an extra voltage gain stage, then use some juicey current amp stage ie emitter follower or source follower to drive the speaker. With the output stage you then just duplicate ie parallel the transistors to get more power.

Comment: Hmm I wonder who is deserving of the "obtuse" label mentioned by the OP?

Comment: @Andyaka maybe I'm only mostly obtuse today.

Comment: LOL squared and cubed.